# Three bar mechanism problem

Tags: geometry

What I'm looking for is a closed form solution for the following problem. All of this is just 2D. I don't know if this is a good parametrization.

[image]

So we have a quadrilateral, given as four side lengths. Two of the points lie on the x-axis, at $D:=(-d,0)$ and $C:=-D$. The other points are $A$ and $B$. All the side lengths $a$, $b$, and $c:=|A-B|$ are fixed. We define the midpoint $R := \frac{A+B}2$, which defines the line through the origin and $R$. So the problem I'd like to solve is: Given the orientation $\gamma$ of that line, what is $r = |R|$?

So I thought I could define $R = R(r) = r(\sin \gamma, \cos \gamma)$ as a function of $r$, and find the angles of the triangle $RBD$ using the law of cosines. Then find $B(r)$ from that, set $A = 2R - B$, and solve $|A(r)+D|=a$ for $r$. I *could* go that way, but it seems messy.

There should be 0, 2, or 4 solutions. (Symmetry, plus imagine what happens when you twist $\overrightarrow{AB}$.) This tells me that r is probably the solution of two nested quadratic equations, i.e. the zero of a symmetrical quartic polynomial, $q(r) = 0$, $q(x) = q(-x)$. What's $q$?

Comment: Better title: Three-bar mechanism curve. More info here (in French): http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d/troisbarres/troisbarre.shtml

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's amazing, thank you.